# Is it okay to create multiple processes in a loop in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

```py
def funcA():
    time.sleep(0.5)
    process = Process(target=funcB)
    process.start()

def funcB():
    time.sleep(3)

def main():
    while (True):
        funcA()
```

`funA()` will create many separate processes infinitely. Is this okay? Or is there some better way to do this? Also, if `funcA()` stops executing after 10 runs, `funcB()` will still have many executions left. I want to the program to end only after all these pending processes are done executing.

Comment: You should probably use a process pool with a maximum amount of worker processes.

Comment: No. This is *not* okay. You are creating processes more quickly than they complete so that the number of processes will increase over time indefinitely and you may eventually have to reboot your computer.

Comment: @Booboo I see,  so what would be the suitable alternative here?

Comment: Your "runaway" program is currently doing nothing but burning up CPU cycles and memory resource and solves nothing. And now you are looking for an alternative? Wouldn't it be better to first  post a real problem that has some sort of output so that one might know what type of alternative to suggest?